# Ember 1.10.0 throws "Uncaught Error: Bound attributes are not yet supported in Ember.js"

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I just changed this:

```
  <div {{bind-attr class=":step category.isCurrent:active category.isBeforeCurrent:visited"}}>
```

to this:

```
<div class="step {{category.isCurrent:active}} {{category.isBeforeCurrent:visited}}">
```

and now get:

`Uncaught Error: Bound attributes are not yet supported in Ember.js`

Here is the bower.json I am using:

```
{
  "name": "proj",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "ember": "1.10.0",
    "ember-data": "^1.0.0-beta.14.1",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.11",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader#0.0.4",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.0.2",
    "ember-qunit": "0.1.8",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.4",
    "qunit": "~1.15.0"
  }
}
```

And my package json :

```
{
  "name": "proj",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli": "0.1.7",
    "ember-cli-6to5": "0.2.1",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.3.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "0.0.7",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^0.6.0",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-less": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.1.2",
    "ember-data": "^1.0.0-beta.14.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.8.5",
    "glob": "^4.0.5"
  }
}
```

I followed the steps in the migration guide so not sure what is wrong. On the whole I do like these new changes though, the future is bright.

Comment: Did you install `htmlbars`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute binding is in Ember 1.11, not 1.10.  The [blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html) for the 1.10 release talks more about this upcoming feature.